# MediaSession finishBroadcast() exception

Tags: java, android, exception, exoplayer, android-mediasession

any idea about the cause of this exception?

> 01-10 15:33:43.111 21717-21717/com.music.ofek.iplay E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                         Process: com.music.ofek.iplay, PID: 21717
>                                                                         java.lang.IllegalStateException: finishBroadcast() called outside of a broadcast
>                                                                             at android.os.RemoteCallbackList.finishBroadcast(RemoteCallbackList.java:292)
>                                                                             at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat$MediaSessionImplApi21.setPlaybackState(MediaSessionCompat.java:3226)
>                                                                             at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat.setPlaybackState(MediaSessionCompat.java:608)
>                                                                             at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ext.mediasession.MediaSessionConnector.updateMediaSessionPlaybackState(MediaSessionConnector.java:521)
>                                                                             at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ext.mediasession.MediaSessionConnector.access$400(MediaSessionConnector.java:69)
>                                                                             at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ext.mediasession.MediaSessionConnector$ExoPlayerEventListener.onPlayerStateChanged(MediaSessionConnector.java:652)
>                                                                             at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImpl.handleEvent(ExoPlayerImpl.java:462)
>                                                                             at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImpl$1.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImpl.java:100)
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5568)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: `com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)` - Look at that, better yet post that code and let us see what is going on

Answer (score 0):

Calling mediaSession.setActive(true) solved the problem